# Count and show Clicks on external links in a single page/post WORDPRESS

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, analytics, tracking

I have the following scenario:
a post that calls a table by shortcode. The table contains links to outside hosts (mediafire,dropbox..etc).
I want to track how many times all the links from that specific post is clicked, and show that count in the post itself.

Is it possible?

Comment: use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/linker/

Comment: stackoverflow is only for programming related platform where you can post your question with some code of example what you already try and failed to figure out read http://stackoverflow.com/tour.

Comment: Sorry, do you know of some wordpress related questions board?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/  try this one

Answer (score 0):

There are a tons of plugin available but u can use [Linker](https://wordpress.org/plugins/linker/). This will works good with your condition.

Comment: Is there is an automatic way to do so? The links exceeds 100000 link